# No Provisiong profiles with a valid signing identity were found and Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, archive, ios-provisioning

I have my ios Project running smoothly till yesterday. Today i have to give one build to `TestFlightAap` generated a new `Adhoc` `provisioning profile` by adding one additional device to my provisioning profile. I have deleted the old `provisioning profile` and when i used the new one which i had generated, it starts giving me the following error.

[image].

If i press fix issue it uses `Automatic` in the `provisioning profile` selection and allow me to `archieve` it but when i try to export the IPA it starts giving me the following error.

[image].

The very same thing happened on another Mac where i am able to do the `archieve` before but when i used the new provisioning profile it starts giving me the same error.

When i checked the `Distribution certificate` in XCode`Preferences ==> Accounts ==> View Details. The status for`Distribution certificate`is`Revoked`. But its not the same on the other MAC where this problem happened. I am using XCode 6.1

[image]

Can some body guide me how i can successfully `archieve` with the `provisioning profile` i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have created a new provisioning profile using certificates the private key for which have been deleted from your keychain. Or the certificate has been created from another mac. I have faced such issues and the best solution is to create a new certificate and a new provisioning profile.

Comment: You are right. I already got it working by creating a new certificate in developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

In Developer Account Download New Profile Follow This Step I Hope This One is Help Full

```
 1. go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in the Developer Center 

    2. create a new provisioning profile in "Provisioning Profiles" / "Distribution"

    3. download the profile and open it 

    4. restart Xcode
```

Comment: You Properly install This Certificate in Your X code

Comment: which certificate you are taking about?

Comment: I have only been able to solve this by using Xcode -> Organizer -> Developer Profile and there clicking Export in the bottom of the right pane. This saves a consolidated .developerprofile file that you cat just open/import on the target machine.

Comment: Other wise You Want Export That